# Implement responsive gui with sleep without backgroundworker

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker, invoke

I have this code, which holds a Sleep. Gui doesn't response well, although Invoke. When I did it with backgroundWorker, then the Gui responses well.
Can this be done only with backgroundWorker? and if so, then why.

Thank you.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((_) => F());
    }
    private void F()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(HardWork));
    }

    private void HardWork()
    {
        label1.Text += "x";
        Thread.Sleep(300);
    }
```

Comment: The invoke is exactly the reason why it doesn't respond well. It causes the code to run on the UI thread. Is there a reason for not using `BackgroundWorker` or just curiosity?

Comment: If you invoke sleep(ms) on the main thread the application will become unresponsive. There are multiple ways for handling threads in c#. Async Await, Background worker, "Native thread", etc.

Comment: But i must use Invoke to update the label in the gui thread

Comment: Is this functionality called from a separate thread (not the gui thread)?

Comment: The ThreadPool above starts the method F().  My question is, how does the backgroundWorker  succeeds to do the gui responsive, if sleep is involved here

Comment: It is correct to use invoke to update the GUI but why do you write the `Thread.Sleep(300)` inside the `HardWork()` ?

Comment: @user3344394 Invoke is called *only* for UI updates, not for the work. Exactly as you would with `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: the sleep just imitate a state when a hard calculation is needed, for example to show result on the label

Comment: The backgroundworker makes the GUI reponsive by running the Sleep from the backround thread. When you sleep on the main thread the GUI "sleeps"

Comment: The idea is to do all of the 'hard calculation' in the background and only invoke to update the label value. You have to separate the `HardWork()` into worker and updater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this be done only with BackgroundWorker?

No. `BackgroundWorker` is just a helper class which delegates the work to threadpool only.

> Then what is wrong with your code?

You're sleeping in UI thread which is responsible for running the message loop. When you block it with Sleep, it can't run the message loop and thus the UI is not responsive.

You probably intended to sleep in worker thread. You do it as follows

```
private void F()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(HardWork));
       Thread.Sleep(300);//Sleep in worker thread, not in UI thread
    }
}

private void HardWork()
{
    label1.Text += "x";
    //No sleep here. This runs in UI thread!
}
```

Comment: Thank you all very much.

Comment: @user3344394 Does your problem is solved? If yes, you may select the check mark in my answer and mark it as resolved. So that it will help future readers. Refer [how accepting answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I just did it now. Thank you all.